# How to remove directory permissions from ls command piped through awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, pipe, ls, oh-my-zsh

In my ZSH custom config, I have this function:

```
cll() { ls -AlhG "$@" | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));if(k)printf(" %0o ",k);print}'; }
```

It outputs:

```
➜  test cll
total 32
644 -rw-r--r--    1 work  admin     0B Oct  7 18:55 .hidden
644 -rw-r--r--    1 work  admin   480B Aug 22  2016 gulpfile.js
644 -rw-r--r--    1 work  admin   149B Jan  7  2017 index.php
755 drwxr-xr-x  247 work  admin   8.2K Aug 22  2016 node_modules
644 -rw-r--r--    1 work  admin   1.0K Aug 22  2016 test.less
644 -rw-r--r--    1 work  admin   664B Aug 22  2016 test.min.css
755 -rwxr-xr-x    1 work  admin     0B Oct  7 18:54 try
```

It also supports colors, so my executable files and such have pretty colors :)

I want to remove the permissions breakdown column (ex: `-rw-r--r--`) from it. So I want it to look like this:

```
644    1 work  admin     0B Oct  7 18:55 .hidden
644    1 work  admin   480B Aug 22  2016 gulpfile.js
644    1 work  admin   149B Jan  7  2017 index.php
755  247 work  admin   8.2K Aug 22  2016 node_modules
644    1 work  admin   1.0K Aug 22  2016 test.less
644    1 work  admin   664B Aug 22  2016 test.min.css
755    1 work  admin     0B Oct  7 18:54 try
```

I have tried to mess with it, but everything I do, it breaks it. I am open to a completely different method (not piping through `awk`).

---

**Final Solution:**

Thank's to @Skaperen for bringing `cut` to my attention. I double piped the function and it worked great! Here is the output now:

```
➜  test cll
total
 644  work  admin     0B Oct  7 18:55 .hidden
 644  work  admin   480B Aug 22  2016 gulpfile.js
 644  work  admin   149B Jan  7  2017 index.php
 755  work  admin   8.2K Aug 22  2016 node_modules
 644  work  admin   1.0K Aug 22  2016 test.less
 644  work  admin   664B Aug 22  2016 test.min.css
 755  work  admin     0B Oct  7 18:54 try
```

Here is the function from my `aliases.zsh` (config in custom):

```
cll() { ls -AlhG "$@" | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));if(k)printf(" %0o ",k);print}' | cut -c 1-5,21-; }
```

The only thing that would make this perfect, is if I could add a custom column to parse whether it is a "Directory", "File", "Symbolic Link", etc.

Comment: Since your `ls` didn't include `-s` the permissions consistently start at column one, so just `print substr($0,12)`. Also: to make the output aligned I would print all k values (not exclude 0) and use `%03o` format. Even so this loses information about types (dir, symlink, fifo, etc) and permissions that include setuid setgid sticky.

Comment: Cross posted to https://superuser.com/questions/1257180/how-to-remove-directory-permissions-from-ls-command-piped-through-awk

Comment: @StephenRauch Yes, after I posted in one, I second guessed which site it belongs in. So I decided to wait until one took precedence, and deleted the other.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The point is to show the user and group. My assumption from your comment is that I would lose those? Please see my updated answer. The only thing I would like to do now is add a custom column to show "Directory", "File", "Symbolic Link". So I assume I would need the 1st char of the permissions and process it.

Comment: The output from `ls -l` begins with the 'permissions' (I should have corrected to mode bits) in cols 1-10, then a space, then the other fields -- unless you use `-s` which you didn't. So if you take the input line starting at col 12 it will include everything but the mode bits (which you have already partly displayed in octal). If you want type yes you need to keep the first char of the mode field and decode it. The other thing I said you lose is setuid setgid sticky _bits_; these are entirely separate from the user and group, which are _not_ lost.

Comment: Also try creating files with permissions (chmod'ed to) 0003 and 0000 to see why I suggested the other changes I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe it through the command `cut -c 1-3,14-`.  tweak the numbers if you need to adjust it.  Do `man cut` for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I have used cut once or twice, but didn't even think of it! Double piped the function, it is works great: `cll() { ls -AlhG "$@" | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));if(k)printf(" %0o ",k);print}' | cut -c 1-5,21-; }`